# How to debug .bsh file from eclipse or otherwise

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jmeter

I have a .jmx within which there is a .bsh being invoked and it is failing there with the below error: I need to troubleshoot and figure out the root cause. Any pointers in this regard would be great. I have this .jmx being invoked from within Java application but I get the same error during execution both from Java application and Jmeter tool.

2018/09/26 16:18:55 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: source Sourced file: src/test/resources/TT.bsh 
2018/09/26 16:18:55 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: source   Sourced file: src/test/resources/TT.bsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside a global [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Failure in script", ex");
}
```

This way you will have "normal" Java [stacktrace](https://stackify.com/java-stack-trace/) in *jmeter.log* file

Another option is adding [`debug();`](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive to the beginning of your script - this will toggle debugging mode and you will get extra information in the console window where you launch JMeter (in other words in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)))

---

For your consideration: [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the main reason is that [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider migrating to Groovy on next available opportunity.

Comment: You must be having a line like `vars.put("foo", bar)` somewhere in your script and the `bar` value is null therefore it fails

Comment: vars.put("message", null); Bingo to this comment. Yes I did see this line: You must be having a line like vars.put("foo", bar) somewhere in your script and the bar value is null therefore it fails
[Log snapshot: // Debug: args[0] = message type = class java.lang.String
java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: Without seeing the code and full log - unfortunately no

Comment: Got you. Any idea why this line might have been used:
vars.put("message", null);

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thank you for the suggestion for using Groovy over .bsh earlier. Did you mean to say that I can call a groovy script from .jmx instead of the current .bsh ?

Comment: Currently, I have a requirement where I need to validate the results of a .jmx within a junit test in Java. And this .jmx has a .bsh invocation within as stated earlier. Now I can see from the jmeter console GUI that there is no response value being captured indicating the status of the response example: success or failure. Is there any way I can get a status indicator so that I can use the same in junit response validation. Can this be done regardless of whether I use .bsh or groovy script within .jmx script ?

Comment: // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
        //boolResultJmeter = jmeter.run(); I wanted to check if something like this is possible because the jmeter.run returns void. 
  assertTrue(true);
  //assertTrue(boolResultJmeter);